# How do I create a command corresponding to this .tex

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, minted

How do I create a command corresponding to this document:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\definecolor{fondtitre}{RGB}{85,85,85}
\definecolor{fonddeboite}{RGB}{232,232,232}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% la boite
\node[rectangle,draw=fondtitre!100,fill=fonddeboite!100,inner sep=10pt,inner ysep=20pt] (mabox)
{
\begin{minipage}{12cm}
\begin{minted}{python}
my fist arg
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
};
% le titre de la boite
\node[fill=fondtitre!100, text=white, rectangle] at (mabox.north){\sffamily\textbf{My second arg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Where "my first arg" and "my second arg" are the two arguments of my newcommand.

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas.

Comment: Could you be more specific in terms of what you want the command to set? Should it actually set everything you currently have within the `document` environment?

Comment: You should look at the `tcolorbox` package

Comment: Yes Werner, everything i have within the document. A new command with two inputs "#1=my first arg" and "#2=my second arg".
Sorry for my english....

Comment: Welcome! You should take @egreg 's advice. You need, presumably, to handle verbatim material and, anyway, why reinvent the wheel in triangular shape when there's this nice round one for the taking?

Comment: @cfr thank you!
Just I thought it was prettier and i can put a title but if it is too complicated it doesn't matter ^^.

Comment: You can make it as pretty as you like with `tcolorbox`. Did you look at the manual?

Comment: @cfr sorry i was busy yesterday, i will look today.

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't compile your code, but I think you want to obtain something like

[image: ![enter image description here]

which can be easily done with `tcolorbox` help. Following code declares a new environment `mycode` with a mandatory argument (box title) and an optional argument (which can help to change default definition). Inside this environment you can write your code.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[french]{babel} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\definecolor{fondtitre}{RGB}{85,85,85}
\definecolor{fonddeboite}{RGB}{232,232,232}

\newtcblisting{mycode}[2][]{%
     listing engine=minted, minted language=python,
     width=12cm,
    enhanced, title=#2, colframe=fondtitre!100, 
    colback=fonddeboite!100, sharp corners,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries, coltitle=white,
    attach boxed title to top center = {yshift=-.5mm} ,
    boxed title style={sharp corners, colback=fondtitre!100},
    listing only,#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{mycode}{My second arg}
my first arg
\end{mycode}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\begin{mycode}[colback=red!30, width=8cm]{Another second arg}
Another first arg
\end{mycode}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

*Note* As Konrad Rudolph pointed original code was not correct for `minted` and `python` so I've added the use of `minted` tcolorbox library, `minted` as listing engine and `python` as the desired language. It's suposed to be correct but my `minted` system fails and I cannot test the solution. The result shown at top was done with a previous version of this code which doesn't use `minted`. I'll try to solve the problem and show a correct result.

*Update:* After solving the problem with `minted+MikTeX` I can confirm that previous code works. An example with `python` code and several `tcolorbox` formating options follows:

```
\begin{mycode}[colback=red!10, width=8cm, drop fuzzy shadow]{Another second arg}
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    print "Hello, World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
\end{mycode}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost there, but this won’t highlight the Python code, which is what the OP was using minted for.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for pointing it. I've added what are supposed to be the correct options but I can not test it because my minted system fails. As soon as I can correct it I'll confirm this solution. If in the mean time you want to edit or post another solution, please, feel free to do it.